# Using Html and Javascript in Flutter

Tags: javascript, html, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am using **peerJS** for screen sharing feature and flutter for **web app**, I'm able to call javascript functions in flutter but not able to pass values from Javascript and Flutter and make them listen in flutter.

this is my `script.js`:

```
const PRE = "Devcom"
const SUF = "Community"
var room_id;
var getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
var local_stream;
var screenStream;
var peer = null;
var currentPeer = null
var screenSharing = false
function createRoom() {
    console.log("Creating Room")
    let room = document.getElementById("room-input").value;
    if (room == " " || room == "") {
        alert("Please enter room number")
        return;
    }
    room_id = PRE + room + SUF;
    peer = new Peer(room_id)
    peer.on('open', (id) => {
        console.log("Peer Connected with ID: ", id)
        hideModal()
        getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, (stream) => {
            local_stream = stream;
            setLocalStream(local_stream)
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })
        notify("Waiting for peer to join.")
    })
    peer.on('call', (call) => {
        call.answer(local_stream);
        call.on('stream', (stream) => {
            setRemoteStream(stream)
        })
        currentPeer = call;
    })
}

function setLocalStream(stream) {

    let video = document.getElementById("local-video");
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.muted = true;
    video.play();
}
function setRemoteStream(stream) {

    let video = document.getElementById("remote-video");
    video.srcObject = stream;
    video.play();
}

function hideModal() {
    document.getElementById("entry-modal").hidden = true
}

function notify(msg) {
    let notification = document.getElementById("notification")
    notification.innerHTML = msg
    notification.hidden = false
    setTimeout(() => {
        notification.hidden = true;
    }, 3000)
}

function joinRoom() {
    console.log("Joining Room")
    let room = document.getElementById("room-input").value;
    if (room == " " || room == "") {
        alert("Please enter room number")
        return;
    }
    room_id = PRE + room + SUF;
    hideModal()
    peer = new Peer()
    peer.on('open', (id) => {
        console.log("Connected with Id: " + id)
        getUserMedia({ video: true, audio: true }, (stream) => {
            local_stream = stream;
            setLocalStream(local_stream)
            notify("Joining peer")
            let call = peer.call(room_id, stream)
            call.on('stream', (stream) => {
                setRemoteStream(stream);
            })
            currentPeer = call;
        }, (err) => {
            console.log(err)
        })

    })
}

function startScreenShare() {
    if (screenSharing) {
        stopScreenSharing()
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true }).then((stream) => {
        screenStream = stream;
        let videoTrack = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        videoTrack.onended = () => {
            stopScreenSharing()
        }
        if (peer) {
            let sender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
                return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
            })
            sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
            screenSharing = true
        }
        console.log(screenStream)
    })
}

function stopScreenSharing() {
    if (!screenSharing) return;
    let videoTrack = local_stream.getVideoTracks()[0];
    if (peer) {
        let sender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
            return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
        })
        sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
    }
    screenStream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
        track.stop();
    });
    screenSharing = false
}
function alertMessage(text) {
    alert(text)
}


window.logger = (flutter_value) => {
   console.log({ js_context: this, flutter_value });
}
window.state = {
    hello: 'world'
}
```

I am able to call these javascript functions in my flutter app using:

```
import 'dart:js' as js;

js.context.callMethod('alertMessage', ['Flutter is calling upon JavaScript!']);
```

I have `webRTC.html` file below which works fine with my js file attached above:

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>DEVCOM - Rooms</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <h1 class="title">Devcom</h1>
    <p id="notification" hidden></p>
    <div class="entry-modal" id="entry-modal">
        <p>Create or Join Meeting</p>
        <input id="room-input" class="room-input" placeholder="Enter Room ID">
        <div>
            <button onclick="createRoom()">Create Room</button>
            <button onclick="joinRoom()">Join Room</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="meet-area">
        <!-- Remote Video Element-->
        <video id="remote-video"></video>

        <!-- Local Video Element-->
        <video id="local-video"></video>
        <div class="meet-controls-bar">
            <button onclick="startScreenShare()">Screen Share</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/peerjs@1.3.1/dist/peerjs.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

</html>
```

but the problem which I am facing is how can I make a flutter widget listen to javascript like instead of using  `document.getElementById("room-input").value` I want to make javascript listen to flutter **widgets and variables** rather than **html id**, values...

or Is there any other way which can make html rendering in flutter web I tried `webview_flutter`, `easy_web_view`, `flutter_html` but nothing worked for me as I want to use it in windows chrome (web) few of earlier mentioned plugins are rather **legacy** and other are **only for android and ios**

Comment: did you find the answer for this ?

Comment: Nope but I did get an alternative way to do what I wanted to achieve but it isnt the perfect solution so still waiting for proper solution

Comment: Any idea how should I proceed for video calling app in flutter. Wanted to use peerjs.

Comment: @shubhamsachan I would recommend you to use webRTC rather than peerjs, I used peerjs just for fun but webRTC is more dynamic and widely used.

Comment: Have you tried using the https://pub.dev/packages/js library to implement callbacks via interop?